# Numeric point characters in r do not fully show

Tags: r, plot, point, pch

[image]

Above is an image of a simple plot I have created with x,y co-ordinates.
I have passed `pch = as.character(1:32)` into the plot, but after the first 9 characters, it will cut off the second character. How do you fix this? I guess I need to increase the width of each point?

Thanks!

Comment: You can only have a single character as a point, not a string containing multiple characters

Answer (score 3):

You could use `text` with argument `label` like this:

```r
df <- data.frame(x = c(rep(1:5, each = 5)),
                 y = c(rep(1:5, 5)))

plot(df$x, df$y, type='n')
text(df$x, df$y, label = 1:25)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>